# Every time I launch the vscode, it automatically opens launchd.conf. How do I turn this off?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Every time I launch the vscode, it automatically opens launchd.conf. How do I turn this off.
[image]

Comment: Does every folder you open with VSCode show the `launchd.conf`? Please give a few more details regarding the file tree of that project.

Answer (score 0):

VSCode always opens the folder on which you were **previously** working.

Try opening a new folder `File > Open Folder > {Some_Folder}`, and close VSCode.

Now whenever you open VSCode again, it loads `{Some_Folder}`.